# How do you call constructor via child class?

Tags: php, oop, class, object, constructor

I need to call the constructor of the following class Foto

```
class Foto extends Galerie
{
    function __construct($a,$b)
    { }
}
```

via its child class. Something like:

```
class Album extends Foto
{
    function __construct($a,$b)
    { return $this->Foto[__construct] }
}
```

Any ideas? Hope you'll get my point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
parent::__construct($a,$b)
```

Is what you're looking for. You can also call parent class methods utilizing the same keyword.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the parent constructor by doing:

```
parent::__construct($a, $b);
```

Now that we got that out of the way:

Please give your variables decent names. `$a` and `$b` tells nothing. Also I'm really wondering whether you should really extend those classes. Read about the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Comment: Thanks a lot. They're not named like that, I thought it would be an easier way to display my problem.

Great, I'll take a look at it, as I'm just learning OOP.

Comment: If you are just starting out read about the [SOLID principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) and watch [these videos](http://www.g-truc.net/post-0182.html).

Comment: Thanks! I'll definitely do that.